# Hiding OAuth2 Client Secret

Tags: python, security, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm creating a Python script using the Google OAuth2 authentication "system", however, I'm not sure how to hide the client key. The files will have to be downloaded to use the program, and the intention is oviously that others will use the program as well.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You can't if you are releasing the script for others to use then you can't embed your own Client_id you will need to instruct your users in creating their own though the developer console.

Comment: DaimTo's comments are correct. It might be worth explaining a bit more about what your script does and how you intend to distribute it, and how users will user it  to see if there is a workaround, or if you need a bit of direction on OAuth.